# Shifting all elements of an array back one in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a code that will shift all elements of an array back one, and move the last element to the front of the array.

I pretty much want my program to do this:

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
// do something such that array will become {3, 1, 2}
```

My code is as follows:

```
int[] array = new int[3];


for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  array[0] = 1;
  array[1] = 2;
  array[2] = 3;
  int last = array[array.length-1];
  array[i] = array[i+1];
  array[0] = last;

  System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

I thought that adding 1 to "i" for the array, and storing the last element of the array in "last" and assigning it to array[0] would do the trick, but I'm just getting {3, 3} in the output with "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3."

Comment: Did you mean shuffle or shift?

Comment: Why are you assigning the first three indexes in every loop?

Comment: You need to think through which stuff happens inside the loop and which stuff happens before or after it.

Comment: Err... `array[i] = array[i+1]` is the problem... try `array[i] = array[(i+1)%array.length]`. Make sure to use a temporary array too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with something like this:

```
int[] originalArray = ...
int[] shiftedArray = new int[originalArray.length];

System.arraycopy(originalArray, 0, shiftedArray, 1, originalArray.length - 1);
shiftedArray[0] = originalArray[originalArray.length - 1];
```

**EDIT**
As suggested, only one array is actually needed

```
int[] originalArray = ...
int lastItem = originalArray[originalArray.length - 1];

System.arraycopy(originalArray, 0, originalArray, 1, originalArray.length - 1);
originalArray [0] = lastItem;
```

Comment: I edited your answer to correct the method name.  The method name isn't camel-cased.

Comment: You don't even need to copy the array (you can have the `src` and `dest` arrays be the same, according to the docs).

Comment: Haven't thought about that, it is a nice improvement. I updated my answer based on that.

Comment: This is what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If what you really want is to rotate it (sounds a bit like it).
Use [Collections.rotate()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_rotate.htm):

```
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(array), 1);
```

Where 1 is the number of steps (distance)

If you don't want to convert the array to a list you could do the rotate manually with simple methods like this (for example)

**Going left:**

```
void rotateArrayLeftByOne(int array[])
{
    // get last index of array
    int lastIndex = array.length - 1; 
    // save first element
    int oldFirst = array[0]; 

    // copy the elements from  right to left
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) 
        array[i] = array[i + 1];

    // put the first element last
    array[lastIndex] = oldFirst;
}
```

**and going right:**

```
void rotateArrayRightByOne(int array[])
{
    // get last index of array
    int lastIndex = array.length - 1; 
    // save last element
    int oldLast = array[lastIndex]; 

    // copy the elements from  left to right
    for (int i = lastIndex; i != 0; i--) 
        array[i] = array[i - 1];

    // put the last element first
    array[0] = oldLast;
}
```

Comment: I didnt know about this rotate method, nice and simple +1

Comment: Didn't know about that method either. But to avoid the conversion to a List, it's pretty trivial to implement using `System.arraycopy()`, especially for a single step.

Comment: If you actually try running this, it will not work.  You are rotating the `List` you created, but not the original array.

Comment: @azurefrog and whats stopping him from creating a new array / repopulating the original from the list?

Comment: @MarkW Nothing at all.  I'm just pointing out that a) such a step is required and b) such a step is not mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @azurefrog Thank you! I added another manual solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying access an index that does not exist in your array. Your array's size is 3 therefore 2 is the last index. Also, you are initializing and printing in the for loop. You should do those outside of the loop.

```
int[] array = new int[3];

array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;

for(int i = 0, previous_value = array[array.length]; i < array.length; i++)
{
  int prev = array[i];
  array[i] = previous_value;
  previous_value = prev;
}

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With O(1) space and O(n) time.

```
int[] array = new int[3];

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) array[i] = i;

int temp = array[array.length-1];

for(int i = array.length-1; i > 0; i--) array[i] = array[i-1];

array[0] = temp;
```

Comment: This can be done in `O(n)` time with `O(1)` extra space

Comment: I should brush up on my O(n) derivations :P

Comment: And there is an `arrayOutOfBoundsException` in your code. Guess it is a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem is that actually your are triying to access a element that doesn't exists.
Whe you run this code

```
array[i] = array[i+1];
```

and the "i" variable is 2, doing i + 1 will lead you to array[3] which doesn't exists.

Also, working directly with array can lead to memory consumption problems if you are triying to sort, you should better using collections, check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/ for a good tutorial on how to handle this kind of operations

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate from end to begin. You begin with creating an empty slot in the end, then start to fill the empty slot with the previous value. There is no need of creating a temporary array. Everything is done `in place`.

```
int n=3;
int[] array = new int[n];
int last = array[n-1];    //copy last element into buffer thus creating an empty slot
for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--)    //iterate from end to begin
{
   array[i] = array[i-1]; //push previous element into current location(an empty slot)
}
array[0] = last;          //finally put the last element into initial slot
```